# Python version mismatch: module was compiled for Python 3.6, but the interpreter version is incompatible: 3.9.8

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, cpython

In order to install the newest `tensorflow`(2.7.0), I updated my `python3` verison from `3.6.6` to `3.9.8`. Here is how I do it inside my **docker**!!.

```
Download the Python-3.9.8.tgz file

1. tar -xf Python-3.9.8.tgz

2. cd Python-3.9.8 & ./configure --enable-optimizations

3. make -j 12

4. make altinstall
```

And my `python3 --version` is `Python 3.9.8`. However, as I am trying to load the newest `tf` by `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf`. Here comes the error:

```
  File "/workspaces/model/task.py", line 120, in new_model_test
    import model_api
  File "/lfs/biomind/model_tmp/19bddfc44e8211ecbe172d8a58f5e38e/wmh_v2/model_api.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 2453, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.util import deprecation
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging as logging
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/platform/tf_logging.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import tf_export
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/tf_export.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.util import tf_decorator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/tf_decorator.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.util import tf_stack
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/tf_stack.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import _tf_stack
ImportError: Python version mismatch: module was compiled for Python 3.6, but the interpreter version is incompatible: 3.9.8 (main, Nov 25 2021, 21:54:13) 
[GCC 7.5.0].
```

Is there a way to change the compiled version of `Python` or do I do something which is not the right step? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For my question, the issue starts from `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py"`. Though I installed `Python3.9`, python search `python3.6` lib as well. The solution is simple: delete `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/`